# SQL query to get max of a column and display with every row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my scenario... 
Multiple Items with multiple item types which have multiple prices.
Want to select Items with all types showing the MAX price. Can't figure out how to get the max?

Input:

```
ProductId   ProductType Description     Price
```

1           A           BAKED BEANS     1.29

1           B           BAKED BEANS     1.98

Output:

```
ProductId   ProductType Description     Price
```

1           A           BAKED BEANS     1.98

1           B           BAKED BEANS     1.98

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT ProductId, 
    ProductType,
    Description,
    b.price
  FROM <YOUR_TABLE> a, 
        (SELECT MAX(price) price FROM <YOUR_TABLE>) b
```

For those who love ANSI syntax:

```
SELECT ProductId, 
    ProductType,
    Description,
    b.price
  FROM <YOUR_TABLE> a INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(price) price FROM <YOUR_TABLE>) b
   ON 1=1
```

Comment: Although, I would never recommend using the comma-separated syntax. The day will come when SQL Server will stop supporting it (if only it could happen sooner).

Comment: @Thomas: Updated the post with ANSII version of join

Answer (score 3):

```
Select ProductId, ProductType, Description, MaxByDesc.MaxPrice
From Product
    Join    (
            Select Description, Max(Price) As MaxPrice
            From Product 
            Group By Description
            ) As MaxByDesc
        On MaxByDesc.Description = Product.Description
```

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later:

```
Select ProductId, ProductType, Description
    , Max( Price ) Over ( Partition By Description ) As MaxPrice
From Product
```

Comment: It works. Thanks so much! I am using ROW_NUMBER() in my subquery to grab newest Price. Didn't know that I could use MAX() with Partition BY...

Answer (score 1):

Thomas, right, except for that you need to group by type:

```
Select ProductId, ProductType, Description, MaxByDesc.MaxPrice
From Product
Join    (
        Select Description, Max(Price) As MaxPrice
        From Product 
        Group By ProductType
        ) As MaxByDesc
    On MaxByDesc.ProductType = Product.ProductType
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
SELECT ProductId
     , ProductType
     , Description
     , ( SELECT MAX(price)
         FROM Product pg
         WHERE pg.Description = p.Description 
       ) AS MaxPrice
  FROM Product p
```